# How could I locate any global corporation which sells to the private sector directly through E-commerce?

Tags: terminology

I understood that in recent years there is a tendency for some corporations (such as Coca Cola and Mutti<sup>[1](https://www.globes.co.il/news/article.aspx?did=1001324532)</sup> at least in some countries) to sell directly to retail customers / private sector, if the order is big enough (say, 100 bottles?), via E-commerce.

I assume that it's not only Coca Cola so I would like to learn how could I locate **any** global corporation which sells to the private sector directly through E-commerce?

Is there any term to describe corporations which distribute this way?

"CCSO" (Conglomerates Corporations Selling Selling Online).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's just spam.

Comment: Since when seeking a standard term / term in the very recent literature is spam?...

Comment: @retailer thanks for the accept, but please don't try to sneak the spam into my answer. I understand that your intention was to promote your company, that's not what this site is for.

Comment: @littleadv what? My company? I don't have any company and never registered a company... It's so funny, this website being so Americo-centric or however one should phrase it... Shalom/Salam/Namaste from the other less illuminated world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of the Israeli company (the article you linked to), it's not "Coca Cola", it's "[The Central Bottling Company](https://www.dnb.com/business-directory/company-profiles.the_central_bottling_company_limited.55ba216afec16e93c91e98523b387080.html)" which holds the rights to manufacture and distribute Coca Cola products in Israel.

More broadly there's no simple answer to your question. The type of sale you're referring to is called "[retail sale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retail)", as opposed to "[wholesale sale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wholesaling)" to distributors. There's no one single database of all the retail sellers in the world (or even a single country, other than maybe tax records).